Upload an Excel sheet with huge number of records to a MySql database in the form of a JSON
I have a requirement in Spring Boot project, where I have a huge Excel file with 15-20 sheets, each sheet containing 30,000 rows with an average of 15 columns in each sheet.
My Database is roughly as follows
`CREATE TABLE [Import_Table\](
\[Id\] \[int\] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
\[Sheet_Name\] \[nvarchar\](max) NOT NULL,
\[Request_JSON\] \[nvarchar\](max) NOT NULL,
\[Response_JSON\] \[nvarchar\](max) NULL)`




Id
Sheet_Name
Request_JSON




1
Sheet1
[{"Prop1":"1","Prop2": "2"..},{"Prop1": "11","Prop2":"22"...}


2
Sheet2
[{"Prop11":"1","Prop22": "2"..},{"Prop11": "11","Prop22":"22"...}]



I want to upload all the data from the excel sheet into the table Import_Table in Json format, so that each sheet in the excel file is saved as an individual row in the table.
the processing of the Request_JSON is taken care later on by a change detecting service and Response_JSON is populated.
Iam facing connection timeout issue while sending such huge data. Please suggest an efficient way to resolve the issue.
None of the solution I tried worked so far.

I think posting your code will allow people to understand how you are doing it now which may help them to suggest alternatives - which is what you are asking for.

Why don't you convert the Excel to csv and then import it directly?

Spring batch could be a good solution here. It's designed to handle large volumes and  can help with this task .

You can read data from the Excel sheets using an excel item reader : spring-batch-excel
You can convert data into JSON format as needed using ItemProcessor.
Use an ItemWriter to write the transformed data into the Import_Table .

Why spring batch ?
Spring Batch processes data in chunks, avoiding the need to load the entire file into memory at once. This approach helps manage large data volumes efficiently and mitigates memory-related issues.
